# Kubernetes installing fails on Debian 9

Tags: debian, kubernetes, kubeadm

I am trying to install Kubernetes on my Debian 9 machine. I did anything that official document said. [+](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/)
[+](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/)

I give some errors when I ran `kubeadm init` :

```
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.9.3
[init] Using Authorization modes: [Node RBAC]
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks.
    [WARNING FileExisting-crictl]: crictl not found in system path
[preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
    [ERROR Port-10251]: Port 10251 is in use
[preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can make a check non-fatal 
with 
`--ignore-preflight-errors=...`
```

How Can I fix these errors and install `kubeadm` ?

Comment: It basically says that the files it's trying to install already exist. Check the given paths - did you try installing it manually before? Consider deleting these files.

Comment: @AndreasHartmann I deleted these files that you said and I updated new errors. thanks

Comment: still looks like kubernetes is already running. Try restarting your pc, or use "top" to find the process and kill it, or use this to find out which application is using that port: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-process-has-open-linux-port/

Comment: @AndreasHartmann I ran `ss -lptn 'sport = :10250'` to find which process using 10250 port and i killed it with `kill -9 the PID` also `ran pkill kubelet`. but i gave same errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [ERROR Port-10251]: Port 10251 is in use

Port `10251` is used by `kube-scheduler`. Looks like it is not free due to the previous kubernetes installation. Skipping `preflight` checks won't help here.

I suggest doing the following:

1. [`kubeadm reset`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-reset/) on all the nodes.
2. Reboot all the nodes if possible.
3. `kubeadm init <optional arguments>` on master.
4. `kubeadm join <arguments>` on the worker nodes.

Comment: I followed these steps. When I ran `kubeadm init` its seem freeze and nothing to happen. end of line erroring:
`
[init] This might take a minute or longer if the control plane images have to be pulled.
`

Comment: Can you restart docker daemon and re-try?

Comment: @meysammahmoodi `[init] This might take a minute or longer if the control plane images have to be pulled` is not an error. It is expected and will take a few minutes to proceed. The control plane images should be pulled.

Comment: ok. i restarted docker,`docker restart $(docker ps -q)`, and i did the steps again. so i'm waiting to pulled.

Comment: `docker restart $(docker ps -q)` restarts the containers and **not** the docker daemon itself. Try restarting the docker daemon itself. The command is `sudo systemctl restart docker.service` or `sudo service docker restart` depending on your OS. More info is in https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/.

Comment: @meysammahmoodi Upvote and accept my answer if you think it is useful so that others know this is the right answer, thanks!

Comment: @VikramHosakoteI have a problem yet. I give an timed out error after run `kubeadm init` command. I confused what is wrong! I guess properly my server hardware config is not strong enough. it has 2gb ram and 2core cpu. i am trying to resolve the errors right now. I will accept your answer soon.

Comment: I found the solution Finally. When I upgraded Ram of Server to 4gb from 2gb, it worked as well. Also Thanks from @VikramHosakoteI for helping.